# Unordered tuple as dictionary key

Tags: python

How can I have tuples  or some other datastructure with the property that with the same elements, regardless of order, index to the same value in a dictionary?

Say I have a tuple `(A, B)` as a key to a dictionary `d`. So `d[(A, B)] = 1 and d[(B,A)]) = 1`.  It doesn't have to be a tuple.

Comment: Probably frozenset, but note that frozenset won't distinguish the number of occurrences, either, so `(A, A, B)` will be the same as `(A, B, B)`.

Comment: Another option is to use sorted tuples as keys.

Comment: There's also `frozenset(collections.Counter(your_tuple).items())`, which works nicely for unorderable tuple elements.

Comment: Or a custom tuple subclass which defines `__hash__` as `hash(tuple(sorted(self)))`...

Comment: ^Now could someone please combine all of that into an answer (I'd like to save all of this somewhere :)).

Comment: @DanielRoseman: That doesn't do the right thing with `==`, and if you define `__eq__` to be consistent with that `__hash__`, you break `==` comparisons against regular tuples.