# C# Dictionary that uses an Unordered Pair as its Key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, unordered-set, unordered

I'm trying to create a Dictionary is C# that takes an Unordered Pair of Indices as its Key.

For example:

`exampleDictionary[new UnorderedPair(x,y)]` and `exampleDictionary[new UnorderedPair(y,x)]` should both return the same value.

Is there a way to create a custom unordered collection other than using a HashSet? Or some way to create an unordered Tuple?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443693/unordered-tuple-as-dictionary-key) is similar to what I'm trying to accomplish, except in C# rather than python.

Comment: Is it so that you would want the x and y to be processed to return the same unique key? Then x + y is same as y + x. If x and y are any type, then you would need to convert them first like if it's string, add x and y hash values so it is sure to be unique.

Comment: A tuple is not the same as an unordered pair (referring to the other question you provided). The `new` keyword creates a new instance of a class and I don't think that this approach will ever work, because if an object is used as a key, then you need to reuse that same object to access the elements of the Dictionary. What are you even trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: @ewerspej It can work; it does not have to be the same object instance. Either you override both `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` inside your `UnorderedPair` type (if you use a struct, also consider implementing `IEquatable<UnorderedPair>`). _Or else_ you create a custom equality comparer (make another class `UnorderedPairEqualityComparer` that has `EqualityComparer<UnorderedPair>` as base class, and send in an instance of this comparer when you create your `exampleDictionary`, instead of relying on the default equality comparer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*If the type is not your own or you can't or don't want to modify refer to [Theodor Zoulias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74052588/7111561)*

Otherwise, assuming that `UnorderedPair` is your own class you can modify what you could do is e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class UnorderedPair<T> : IEquatable<UnorderedPair<T>>
{
    public T X;
    public T Y;

    public UnorderedPair()
    {
        
    }

    public UnorderedPair(T x, T y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public bool Equals(UnorderedPair<T> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // For equality simply include the swapped check
        return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y) || X.Equals(other.Y) && Y.Equals(other.X);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((UnorderedPair<T>)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // and for the HashCode (used as key in HashSet and Dictionary) simply order them by size an hash them again ^^
        var hashX = X == null ? 0 : X.GetHashCode();
        var hashY = Y == null ? 0 : Y.GetHashCode();
        return HashCode.Combine(Math.Min(hashX,hashY), Math.Max(hashX,hashY));
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UnorderedPair<T> left, UnorderedPair<T> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UnorderedPair<T> left, UnorderedPair<T> right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

and then e.g.

```
var testDict = new Dictionary<UnorderedPair<int>, string>();
testDict.Add(new UnorderedPair<int>(1,2), "Hello World!");
Console.WriteLine(testDict[new UnorderedPair<int>(2,1)]);
```

---

As per suggestion by Jodrell in the comments you could even make the types swappable - not sure this would be ever needed - but this way you could even have a pair of different types:

```
[Serializable]
public class UnorderedPair<TX, TY> : IEquatable<UnorderedPair<TX, TY>>
{
    public TX X;
    public TY Y;

    public UnorderedPair()
    {
        
    }

    public UnorderedPair(TX x, TY y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public UnorderedPair(TY y, TX x)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // and for the HashCode (used as key in HashSet and Dictionary) simply order them by size an hash them again ^^
        var hashX = X == null ? 0 : X.GetHashCode();
        var hashY = Y == null ? 0 : Y.GetHashCode();
        var combine = HashCode.Combine(Math.Min(hashX, hashY), Math.Max(hashX, hashY));
        return combine;
    }

    public bool Equals(UnorderedPair<TX, TY> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (typeof(TX) != typeof(TY))
        {
            return EqualityComparer<TX>.Default.Equals(X, other.X) && EqualityComparer<TY>.Default.Equals(Y, other.Y);
         
        }
        
        return  EqualityComparer<TX>.Default.Equals(X, other.X) && EqualityComparer<TY>.Default.Equals(Y, other.Y)
            || X.Equals(other.Y) && Y.Equals(other.X);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return obj switch
        {
            UnorderedPair<TX, TY> other => Equals(other),
            UnorderedPair<TY, TX> otherSwapped => Equals(otherSwapped),
            _ => false
        };
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UnorderedPair<TX, TY> left, UnorderedPair<TX, TY> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UnorderedPair<TX, TY> left, UnorderedPair<TX, TY> right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static implicit operator UnorderedPair<TX, TY>(UnorderedPair<TY, TX> pair)
    {
        return new UnorderedPair<TX, TY>(pair.Y, pair.X);
    }
}
```

and

```
var testDict = new Dictionary<UnorderedPair<int, double>, string>();
testDict.Add(new UnorderedPair<int, double>(1,2.5), "Hello World!");
Console.WriteLine(testDict[new UnorderedPair<double,int>(2.5,1)]);
```

---

([.NET Fiddle for both](https://dotnetfiddle.net/scSJla))

Comment: Generally the right idea, I think but, shouldn't the type of X and Y be generic and not necessarily the same.

Comment: @Jodrell generic, yes why not ^^ But `not necessarily the same` would be possible generally but since the `Dictionary` itself is strictly typed anyway it would be no use to be able to compare a `UnorderedPair<Type1, Type2>` to a `UnorderedPair<Type2, Type1>` since the `Dictionary` could anyway only either be of type `Dictionary<UnorderedPair<Type1,Type2>, OtherType>` or `Dictionary<UnorderedPair<Type2,Type1>, OtherType>` so afaik you can only use according key type anyway ... or am I wrong here?

Comment: Well you could of course add some implicit conversions to it though ^^ But not sure if this is going to be a bit overkill

Comment: agreed, different generic types doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Jodrell added it at the bottom via implicit conversion .. not sure if you would ever use it but it can be done ^^

Comment: The `UnorderedPair<TX, TY>` implementation can fail if `TX` and `TY` happen to be the same, although the existence of the "backwards" instance constructor overload makes that less common (but not impossible!). If anybody ever wants something like that, consider a check in a static constructor, like `static UnorderedPair() { if (typeof(TX) == typeof(TY)) throw new NotSupportedException("Types must be different"); }`

Comment: Thanks @JeppeStigNielsen that is really good to know! The two constructors I guess woul actually make it impossible, not declaring the type e.g. `UnorderedPair<int,int>` but latest when creating an instance it will not compile due to "ambigious constructor" ... would you have an idea for actually allowing that? I suspect OP's main attempt would actually be the upper solution for the same type for both values anyway

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen treating this case explicitly like e.g. `if (typeof(TX) == typeof(TY)) { return  EqualityComparer<TX>.Default.Equals(X, other.X) && EqualityComparer<TY>.Default.Equals(Y, other.Y) || X.Equals(other.Y) && Y.Equals(other.X); }` seems to do the trick, what do you think?

Comment: All I know is with the code you had 24 hours ago, it was not completely impossible to make `UnorderedPair<int, int>` as you ask for. For example, with a little method `static UnorderedPair<TOther, int> GetUnorderedPairWithInt32<TOther>(TOther o, int i) => new UnorderedPair<TOther, int>(o, i);` I could get around the problem with two constructor overloads, and then with `var p = GetUnorderedPairWithInt32(5, 8);` and `GetUnorderedPairWithInt32(8, 5)` I could get the problem I described then. But since you have changed your code now, it is now longer relevant, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

You could write a custom [`IEqualityComparer<UnorderedPair<T>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) implementation, and pass it as argument to the constructor of your `Dictionary<UnorderedPair<TKey>, TValue>`. This way you won't have to modify your `UnorderedPair<T>` type, by overriding its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. Below is an example of such a comparer for the [`ValueTuple<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2) struct, with both `T1` and `T2` being the same type:

```
class UnorderedValueTupleEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<(T, T)>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> _comparer;

    public UnorderedValueTupleEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals((T, T) x, (T, T) y)
    {
        if (_comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item1)
            && _comparer.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item2)) return true;
        if (_comparer.Equals(x.Item1, y.Item2)
            && _comparer.Equals(x.Item2, y.Item1)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode((T, T) obj)
    {
        int h1 = _comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Item1);
        int h2 = _comparer.GetHashCode(obj.Item2);
        if (h1 > h2) (h1, h2) = (h2, h1);
        return HashCode.Combine(h1, h2);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
Dictionary<(int, int), string> dictionary = new(
    new UnorderedValueTupleEqualityComparer<int>());
```

Comment: This is a great alternative for types that you do not own and can/want not modify directly

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [@derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74051720/659190) and my comments on it,

[Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YoCE8b)

A generic implementation,

```
#nullable enable
public class UnorderedPair<T> : IEquatable<UnorderedPair<T>>
{
    private static IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    
    public T X { get; }
    public T Y { get; }
    
    public UnorderedPair(T x, T y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public bool Equals(UnorderedPair<T>? other)
    {
        if(other is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        // For equality simply include the swapped check
        return
                comparer.Equals(X, other.X) && comparer.Equals(Y, other.Y)
            ||
                comparer.Equals(X, other.Y) && comparer.Equals(Y, other.X);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as UnorderedPair<T>);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return
                    (X is null ? 0 : comparer.GetHashCode(X))
                +
                    (Y is null ? 0 : comparer.GetHashCode(Y));
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UnorderedPair<T>? left, UnorderedPair<T>? right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UnorderedPair<T>? left, UnorderedPair<T>? right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
#nullable disable
```

Comment: Already made mine generic after your comment btw ;)